# How do I change the style of a prop in <TextField>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm rendering `<TextField>` twice using my defined `DatePicker.js` component. So, whenever the user clicks on the `<CalendarIcon>` which is inside the `<TextField>`, small calendar will open up. I want to style the label in the `<TextField>` in a specific way.
Currently, this is how it looks.

[image]

You can see that 'To' label of the second `<TextField>` is visible. It should come behind the calendar and should not show up.

```
class DatePickerInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      label,
      selectedDate
    } = this.props;
    return (<TextField
        fullWidth
        variant="filled"
        label={label}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
        value={selectedDate.format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
        InputProps={{
          className: classes.input,
          endAdornment: (<CalendarIcon color="primary" />)
        }}
      />)
  }
}
class DatePicker extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {
      label,
      value,
      minDate,
      maxDate,
      onChange
    } = this.props;


    return (
      <ReactDatePicker
        selected={value.toDate()}
        minDate={minDate.toDate()}
        maxDate={maxDate.toDate()}
        customInput={<DatePickerInputComp
          selectedDate={value}
          label={label}
        />}
        onChange={onChange} />
    )
  }
}
```

**The problem:**

How do I make the 'To' label not show up when the `<CalendarIcon>` pops up. I want to style the prop 'label' of TextField but I'm not sure of how I can do it.

**The Updated Code:**

```
const inputStyles = theme => ({
  icon: {
     zIndex: 1029,
   },
});
class DatePicker extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {
      label,
      value,
      minDate,
      maxDate,
      onChange,
    } = this.props;
    const { classes } = this.props;


    return (
      <ReactDatePicker
        selected={value.toDate()}
        minDate={minDate.toDate()}
        maxDate={maxDate.toDate()}
        customInput={<DatePickerInputComp
          selectedDate={value}
          label={label}
        />}
        wrapperClassName={classes.icon}
        onChange={onChange} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just change the z-index of the whole DatePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a higher z index for the react-datepicker component in order to make it visible at the top stack.

```
 <ReactDatePicker
    selected={value.toDate()}
    minDate={minDate.toDate()}
    maxDate={maxDate.toDate()}
    customInput={<DatePickerInputComp
    selectedDate={value}
    label={label}
    wrapperClassName="datePicker"
  />
```

I've added a wrapperClassname `datePicker` in order to make the styling easier.

```
.datePicker{
 z-index: 999
}
```

Temporarily gave the z-index as 999, You can alter it to a lower value after defining a z-index for the text field.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing like this wrapperClassName={icon} How can I define icon in the same Reactjs file? Can it be done using makeStyles?

Comment: I tried it with {classes.icon} and but I'm getting classes as undefined
const inputStyles = theme => ({
  icon: {
     zIndex: 1029,
   },
});
const { classes } = this.props;

Comment: @NehaChaudhary Are you passing the style as prop or defining one inside the same component?

Comment: I'm passing the style as prop. I defined inputStyles outside the class component. And inside the class component const { classes } = this.props; I did this. Now, when I'm using it in wrapperClassName={classes.icon}, I'm getting classes as undefined

Comment: Can you codesandbox or add the updated code?

Comment: @NehaChaudhary Code looks fine. Did you add `export default withStyles(inputStyles)(DatePicker)` in the export ?